# Replace String from all files

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find all CONFIG.INF files and change a specific property to a specific one.

The CONFIG.INF file looks as follows:

```
NAME: A
VERSION: 1.2.0.X
TOPIC: X
```

I want to read such files and replace the last part from the version property of each file.

```
find ${WORKSPACE} -name CONFIG.INF -type f -exec sed -i.bak "s/VERSION:.*/VERSION: ${VERSION}/g" {} \;
```

This replaces the complete version but I want to replace only the last part from the version. According to the example, the version will be 1.2.0.Y if I replace with Y. The last part could be anything (not necessarily X) and I just want to replace the last part.

Comment: The CONFIG.INF looks as follows:
`
NAME: A
VERSION: 1.2.0.X
TOPIC: X
`

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
sed -i.bak "s/VERSION:.*\./&${VERSION_LETTER}/g"
```

That matches the string "VERSION:" followed by as many characters as possible until the **last** dot.

The replacement part contains the magic character `&` which is replaced by *the text that was matched by the regular expression*, followed by the variable that contains the new version letter.